# Prefix search in postgres for autocompletion

Tags: postgresql

I have this problem.

Given a static set of strings (~100000), need to answer queries for strings matching a given prefix, returning only the lexicographically minimum 3.

### Option-1

Store the words and do prefix queries.

```sql
CREATE TABLE words(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  word text
);
CREATE INDEX idx_word on words(word);

SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'FOO%' ORDER BY word limit 3;
```

### Option-2

Precompute the matches for each prefix beforehand and store them in this table, to lookup by prefix.

```sql
CREATE TABLE prefixmatches(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  prefix text,
  matches text[]
);
CREATE INDEX idx_prefix on prefixmatches(prefix);

SELECT matches from prefixmatches where prefix = 'FOO';
```

Option-2 is around 10x-20x faster.

Which of these is a better approach? Is there some other way?

Comment: Nvm, defining a text_pattern_ops index for option-1 gives the same performance.

Comment: the same performance as what?

Comment: `%LIKE` operator finds that string anywhere in the column, you're prefix column is essentially equal to `SUBSTR(word,1,3)`.  Try the first option with that search parameter and try again.